# How to create Mixed Pattern Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am trying to create a mixed pattern dictionary in `Swift` which contains either `String:String` or `String:Dictionary` as below. Can anyone help?

```
var tempDict = ["Electronics":"TV"],["Home":["Kitchen":"Utensils"],["BedRoom":"Bed "],["DiningRoom":"Dining"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing what you really want to do, but you can declare a dictionary like this:

```
var tempDict = ["Electronics":"TV","Home":["Kitchen":"Utensils"],"BedRoom":"Bed ","DiningRoom":"Dining"]
```

Swift (as of 2.2.1) infers the type of `tempDict` as `[String: NSObject]`, so you can use the values with casting:

```
if let electronics = tempDict["Electronics"] as? String {
    print(electronics)
}
if let home = tempDict["Home"] as? [String: String] {
    print(home)
}
```

Comment: I have used inferred type concept as you mentioned and have created my dictionary using your example. thanks !!

Comment: @Max, Swift sometimes makes big mistakes when inferring collection types. In such cases, try adding explicit type annotation like `var tempDict: [String: NSObject]` or `var tempDict: [String: AnyObject]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use AnyObject:

```
var tempDict: [String: AnyObject] = ["Electronics":"TV"]
tempDict = ["Home":["Kitchen":"Utensils"]
           ["BedRoom":"Bed "],
           ["DiningRoom":"Dining"]]



var tempDict = [
    "ElectronicsString" : "TV",
    "HomeDic" : [
        [
            "Kitchen" : "Utensils",
            "BedRoom":"Bed ",
            "DiningRoom":"Dining",
        ]
    ],
    "BetArray" : [
        "cat",
        "dog"
    ]
]
```

By the way, if a dictionary is a big compounded dictionary, the complier of Swift will have error. So you can solve it like this:

```
var tempDict: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "ElectronicsString" : "TV"
]

tempDict["HomeDic"] = [
    [
        "Kitchen" : "Utensils",
        "BedRoom":"Bed ",
        "DiningRoom":"Dining",
    ]
]

tempDict["BetArray"] = [
    "cat",
    "dog"
]
```